# how to position circles in straight row using d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I apologize in advance, as I am entirely new to d3.js in particular and programming in general.  My goal is to draw an SVG circle for each data point in my dataset.  I would like the circles to begin at the top left, and move right until they reach the end of the window, and then start again on the left, but BELOW the previous line of circles that were just drawn.

My global variables are:

```
var counterX = 1;
var counterY = 20;
var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
var rowSize = windowWidth/12; //I chose 20 bc each circle has a Radius of 5.
```

And my x & y attributes are:

```
.attr("cx", function(d, i) { 
    if(i%rowSize==0){counterX == 0}
        else{return counterX++}        
    })
.attr("cy", function(d, i){ 
    if(i%rowSize==0){return 12*counterY++}
        return counterY;
    })
```

I don't understand why the `CounterX` is not reseting when `i%rowSize==0` , and I also can't figure out how to move my Y variable down once a row is fully drawn.

Comment: `counterX == 0` should be `counterX = 0`

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still having the same issue..

Comment: to move down a row i think you have to do: counterY=12*counterY

also, do you format rowsize as integer? i is incremented as integer (1,2,3,4,5), so if rowsize is a float, i%rowsize==0 might never happen;


if not, how big is your dataset? is it possible i/rowsize==0 just does not happen, because rowsize is to big? maybe try giving it a fixed number just to test.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions, both solved my issues!